# PHP Development (LAMP environment) - Confluence or GitHub?

Tags: php, github, lamp, confluence, web-development-server

I have recently been put in charge of our PHP Web Developers (I'm a programmer in general of over 30 years, currently the Salesforce Administrator and sometimes Developer in Apex).   My team members are suggesting both GitHub and Confluence for page versioning, check-out control, being able to review the multiple changes any one of several users could make to any given file before they deploy to the live servers, etc.

I'm curious what would be the better choice for this?  Based solely on reputation and what I'm reading online in general, I'd tend toward GitHub.

The Development server we're getting ready to setup will be AT the webhost (remote to us), local to the live servers.

Thanks for any insights.  ;-)

Comment: Off... topic?  Okay....... I guess I was confused by the Tags available for this very topic that number in the hundreds and thousands respectively.  Oh well.

Comment: webbiedave is saying that this is off topic for stackoverflow because questions are expected to be along the lines of "How do I program this?" But I'd say it's fine because the SO documentation for on-topic and off-topic questions says that if your topic generally covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" Then it's OK.

Comment: FYI, the tags are there for questions about specific *usage* of the tool during a programmers duties.

Answer (score 2):

Confluence is not the tool for what you're attempting to do. Confluence is a great choice for intranet forums or wikis, but it isn't the best for keeping track of updated files. While it could alert interested parties every time a new file is attached to certain pages, or every time a page itself is updated, it isn't really intended for your purposes as described in the question.

Here's a page describing Confluence's usefulness: http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview/team-collaboration-software

Again, I'd emphasize that it's really great for allowing non-programmers to generate wiki-content within groups or for an entire company, but I wouldn't recommend it for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks very much - this seems inline with what I generally understood.  I appreciate it.